# How can I split a tuple in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, tuples

Let's say I passed a value that was a tuple, How would I split it into separate values?

```
 let split x = ?
```

Answer (score 3):

3 ways:

`let split (x, y) = x + y;;
let split = function ->
  (x, y) -> x + y;;
let split xy = match xy with (x, y) -> x + y;;`

Comment: Also:
let add pair =
  let x, y = pair in
  x + y

Comment: Or: let split = fun (x, y) -> x + y

Answer (score 3):

using `fst` and `snd` (resp. first and second),separates the 2 components.

```
let x = 1,2;;
fst x ;;
- : int 1
```

Also, if a is a tuple let's say (1,2) you can write :

```
let (x,y) = a in ...
```

x & y will be set to 1 & 2 resp.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't split on purpose, pattern matching is everywhere in ocaml.

```
Let split (x ,y) = x + y
```

is the right way